# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sipdistutils' while install python-poppler-qt5

Tags: python, poppler

I have been trying to install `python-poppler-qt4` but it shows the error that  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module name sipdistutils`. 
When I tried installing the `sipdistutils`, it again showed the error.

**Error Message**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have found a simillar issue here: https://github.com/wbsoft/python-poppler-qt5/issues/14

I think that `sipdistutils` should be part of `sip` package. Please verify if you have it installed:

```
$ pip freeze | grep sip
sip==4.19.1
```

If there's no output install it with `pip install sip`.

If this won't work some proposed solutions:

1. > It seems like the pip version of sip does not install sipdistutils. To install it from source, you can do that:
   >   
   >   `wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/sip/sip-4.19.3/sip-4.19.3.tar.gz
   >   tar zxvf sip-4.19.3.tar.gz
   >   cd sip-4.19.3
   >   python configure.py
   >   make
   >   make install`
2. > You can get the sipdistutils.py from riverbank's mercurial server, i.e. from [here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/hg/sip/file/14685a6e736e/sipdistutils.py). It is self-contained. Just place it into your Python site-packages folder

Answer (score 1):

It is true that using `sipdistutils` for building python extensions is no longer the way to do things. So, the absolute fix is to modify the build procedure for the package but since I am not in control of that (though I may try to find time to contribute to the project) I did find a work-around.

In our case, on Ubuntu 20.04, we're using `pyenv` with the `virtualenv` plugin to create virtual environments for our applications and it is within these environments where we run into the issue. Did a little digging around and figured out that if you have three source files in your build path, it can be made to work:

- `sipdistutils.py` which is provided by `python3-sip-dev` (apt, v4.19.21)
- `sipconfig.py` which is provided by `python3-sip` (apt, v4.19.21)
- `sipconfig_nd8.py` which is provided by `python3-sip` (apt, v.419.21)

*note: v4.19, these files are not present in newer versions of sip*

Now, simply installing those with `apt` would be enough if we were using the apt installed python, since we are not, I simply copied those three files from their default installed location to a custom path that we are using via `PYTHONPATH`.