# Install Poppler in windows with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pip, pyqt4

I've been trying to install Poppler using the pip command `pip install python-poppler-qt4==0.18.1` but it shows a message like this

```
Downloading/unpacking python-poppler-qt4==0.18.1
Downloading python-poppler-qt4-0.18.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\BOOMER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Boomerang RMS\python-poppler-qt4\setup.py) egg_info for package python-poppler-qt4
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\BOOMER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Boomerang RMS\python-poppler-qt4\setup.py", line 42, in <module>
        import sipdistutils
    ImportError: No module named 'sipdistutils'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\BOOMER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Boomerang RMS\python-poppler-qt4\setup.py", line 42, in <module>

    import sipdistutils

ImportError: No module named 'sipdistutils'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\BOOMER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Boomerang RMS\python-poppler-qt4
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Boomerang\pip\pip.log
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sipdistutils' while install python-poppler-qt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420803/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sipdistutils-while-install-python-poppler)

Comment: Juan,

I encountered similar issues with Poppler on Windows. I wrote a short article and tutorial on how to get it working with Windows Subsytem for Linux.  Here's the article: https://medium.com/@matthew_earl_miller/poppler-on-windows-179af0e50150